# Django template filters - impossible to use urlize and textile chained together

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I found impossibility to use chained filters urlize and textile. Because urlize filter is autoescaping quotes. On the other hand it's impossible to apply urlize after textile output, because of Django's recommendation:

> If urlize is applied to text that already contains HTML markup, things
>   won't work as expected. Apply this filter only to plain text.

Any sequence of filter doesn't work:

```
In [1]: from django.template import Template, Context
In [2]: text = '''"bla":/mo/14086/
   ...: http://bla.com'''
In [3]: Template('{% load markup %}{{ text|textile|urlize }}').render(Context({'text': text}))
Out[3]: u'\t<p><a href="/mo/14086/">bla</a><br />http://bla.com</p>'    
In [4]: Template('{% load markup %}{{ text|urlize|textile }}').render(Context({'text': text}))
Out[4]: u'\t<p>&quot;bla&quot;:/mo/14086/<br /><a href="http://bla.com" rel="nofollow">http://bla.com</a></p>'
```

Does anyone know how to use both filters together?

**UPDATE**:
I'm using Django version 1.4 alpha 1 SVN-17347

Answer (score 0):

Workaround with `with`:

```
{% with text|urlize as urlized %}
  {{ urlized|textile }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Doesn't help - the same result like in my example - line Out[4]